# Function arguments in creating function file dynamically

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a helper function to help me generate new file with function definition. Here are part of the code:

```
def new_function_file(file_name, fun_name, arguments):
  f = open(file_name + ".py", 'w')
  f.write("\tdef " + fun_name + str(("self", ) + arguments) + ":\n")

new_leetcode_file("testfile", "test", ("arr1", "arr2"))
```

However, this would generate "def test('self', 'arr1', 'arr2'):" in testfile.py. I was wondering how to properly parse the arguments without single quote generated?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  Writing Python source code to a file from Python is only useful in rare circumstances.

Comment: Well... I want to write a helper function for online coding challenge, where I need to generate a template for unit-tests of the question along with the question description and the function definition. So I can save some time when doing the coding challenge for job interview.

Comment: I'd suggest to use some templating engine for this – you'll end up with much more readable code for the code generation.

Comment: The main issue is with `str(("self", ) + arguments) + ":\n")` If you get rid of the `str(` and closing `)`, you are creating a tuple with `("self", )` That means the expression `("self", ) + arguments` will return a tuple. Then `str` gives you a string representation of that tuple, which is why you get the parentheses in your output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatted printing might be useful here, along with breaking things down a bit:

```
def new_function_file(file_name, fun_name, arguments):

    f = open(file_name + ".py", 'w')

    # expand the arguments and join with "," separators:
    args = ", ".join(arguments) 
    # use formatted print to put it all together nicely:
    write_string = "\tdef {fn}(self, {ar}):\n".format(fn=fun_name, ar=args)

    f.write(write_string)
```

For your demo input:

```
new_leetcode_file("testfile", "test", ("arr1", "arr2"))
```

The "writestring" will be:

```
'\tdef test(self, arr1, arr2):\n'
```

and you can write this directly to the file without any other punctuation.

Comment: I voted this up rather than the third answer rather than @ForceBru because, while both correct, I think this is more pythonic and compact.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want `'(' + ', '.join(('self',) + arguments) + ')'` rather than `str(('self',) + arguments)`.

With that said, there's *probably* a better way to accomplish whatever it is that you're trying to do ... I'll echo the comment by @SvenMarnach

> "Writing Python source code to a file from Python is only useful in rare circumstances."

What are you actually trying to accomplish with this new python source file that you're generating?

Comment: Aren't you missing a `)` after `arguments`?

Comment: @ForceBru -- Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here you're writing a tuple into your file while you have to write the contents of this tuple.

```
def new_function_file(file_name, fun_name, arguments):
   f = open(file_name + ".py", 'w')
   f.write("\tdef " + fun_name+"(")
   arguments=["self"].extend(list(arguments))
   for x in arguments:
      if x!=arguments[-1]: f.write(x+",")
      else: f.write(x)
   f.write("):\n")
```

Comment: I upvoted the other one because using `join()` is more compact/pythonic. `join()` is the first thing I thought of as well.